# How to prevent modifying blockreward in geth code?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, consensus, block-reward

I found below variables in geth file `'consensus/ethash/consensus.go'`

```
      var (
         FrontierBlockReward       = big.NewInt(5e+18) //.. 
         ByzantiumBlockReward      = big.NewInt(3e+18) //..
         //..
       )
```

I have a question about it.

> If I'm a miner and I modify BlockReward(e.g. 10 ether) as I want and
>   rebuild the code and participate in main-net, when I succeed mining,
>   can I receive modified-BlockReward?
>
> Otherwise, how to handle this problem? and is there source code in
>   geth to  handle it?

Very thank you for your favor

Answer (score 3):

A miner can modify their code to start producing blocks that give them a higher block reward: no one can prevent you from modifying and building code that you run. But, other miners will ignore the blocks you create because they know that your block is not following the consensus rules. Yes, nodes have code that handle ignoring blocks and transactions that do not follow the consensus rules.

Comment: greatly thank you for your answer!! :)
could you give location info of that consensus code in geth?